# Jenkins Swarm plugin - Evironmental variables

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I have latest Jenkins and using it's latest Swarm Plugin.

I have written Ansible modules/roles/playbooks to setup install various tools/configuration on a given target node (which I would like to use as a Swarm slave node).

After Ansible playbook run is complete, I now see a new Slave is created and attached to my Jenkins master but Swarm Plugin's docs (Available Options) doesn't mention how to create ENVIRONMENT variables in the slave. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin

My question is:

1. How can I have multiple slaves created on a same target machine and they all **have their own individual settings** for setting various tools like JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, GRADLE_HOME, PATH etc.
2. How can I set ENVIRONMENT variables for a slave using Swarm plugin? 
   This is required as if I created a slave whose default JAVA is jdk1.7.0_67, then I would like to create another slave whose default JAVA_HOME is jdk1.8.0_45. Similarly, the end goal is to have various flavors of such slaves with various tools if possible, where each slave's tools are slightly different.  I'll assign the LABEL(s) accordingly and use it in a Jenkins job's configuration so that a job runs only using / on these slave if the associated label is assigned/tied to the job.

I tried using https://github.com/MovingBlocks/GroovyJenkins/blob/master/src/main/groovy/AddNodeToJenkins.groovy but not sure how I can automatically define/set ENVIRONMENT variables in the slave's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running on Linux here.

You can have a shell script to export the new environment before calling the swarm-client. These variables will be inherited by the new swarm slave
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export

Alternatively you could run docker and have a separate swarm slave containers https://hub.docker.com/r/csanchez/jenkins-swarm-slave/ and put your specific install into the Dockerfile and add a new ENTRYPOINT in the bottom of the Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave.sh" \
    "-labels", "label1", "-labels", "label2"]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Actually I did try setting ~/.bash_profile with PATH=~/tools/bin and in ~/tools/bin, I created symlinks pointing to the default tools locations and in ~/.bash_profile, I exported all tool variables i.e. export JAVA_HOME=~/tools/bin/jdk1.8.0_45; export GRADLE_HOME=... ; export GRADLE_USER_HOME=../.gradle etc and everything worked BUT... just for one slave only (i.e. I overcame the situation of not having any ENV variables created by default by the swarm plugin) using ~/.bash_profile export <Tool>=<Value>. But, I don't know how well this approach will work, if I have 2/more slaves.

Comment: With the existing approach, if I have more than one slave and DONT Manually set the ENVIRONMENT tools locations/values in the SLAVE's configuration, then I'll face problems like which JAVA / GRADLE/ etc a slave will pick while a job runs on that slave (have to do some workarounds but that's not suitable maintenance wise). I'll try the Docker way (as that seems promising and will probably take less time).